# registring on gcm multiple time from same device will generate multiple id or same and multiple users on same device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, node-gcm

I want to know If I am registering my android app multiple time on gcm from same device will I get different registration id each time or the same one once registered?

Coming onto my second problem which is as below

- if user1 logs out and user2 logs in the app on the same device. Now suppose a notification for user1 is sent from the server. Will the user2 get that notification or not if yes then how can it be avoided?
- if user1 is logged in the app but user2 re-installs the app and logs in but server still thinks that user1 is logged in that device hence when we send the notification to user1 it will be delivered to user2. How can these be handled?
- if my andriod app tries to register multiple time on gcm, will it get
  different registration id or the same one?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this will be handled by GCM but as stated in this [forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2qyyuf/notifications_with_gcm_handling_multiple_users_on/) the solution would be to filter them on the client side. Your GCM notification should pass on which user it is for. Then in your `onReceive` method you should check who is currently logged in.

For your last question, according to the documentation - [Registering:Client Apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)

> If a bug in the client app triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and the client app might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> Implementing canonical IDs can help you more easily recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is the registration token of the last registration requested by the client app . This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.
>
> If you try to send a message using an old registration token, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the registration token stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the old registration token will stop working.